# Database stored sentences for checking class status

Tags: c#, .net

I am inheriting a system in C#. I have lots of instructions in the database as follows:

```
StartReal.IsEmpty() && EstimatedStart.Date < DateTime.Today.Date 
StartReal.IsEmpty() && EstimatedStart.Date > DateTime.Today.Date 
StartReal.IsEmpty() && EstimatedStart.Date == DateTime.Today.Date
```

All fields belong to a class called TASKS. Now I'm breaking down each one of the sentences (splitting by AND/OR and by operator) and then doing the analysis of the sentence to have the desired result. This is leading to a very low performance. Is there any other type of operation that can be done?

**Edit**: I'm obtaining a List from the DB that each one has RULECODE, DESCRIPTION and EXPRESSION (the ones above).
Then I'm splitting each expression twice:

```
  private int TaskSituation(TasksBOL pTask, List<SituationRulesBOL> pRules)
  {
     string[] aCommands;
     char[] aSeparators = { '&', '|' };
     char[] aOperators = { '=', '<', '>' };

     int iCode = 0;

     foreach (SituationRulesBOL o in pRules)
     {
        string sExpression = o.Expression;

        if (sExpression.Contains("&&") || sExpression.Contains("||"))
        {
           aCommands = sExpression.Split(aSeparators, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }

        iCode = CheckExpression(pTask, aCommands);
     }

     return iCode;
  }
```

The previous method gets each part of the sentence and splits it for AND/OR. Then it passes the Task information and the senteces to CheckExpression and makes another split by operator and compares to the Task dates.

Comment: Could you show us  your new code please? Also, if this is working/production code that you just want reviewed, [codereview.se] might be the better site to ask your question on.

Comment: I've edited the question with part of the code for you to have an idea how I'm going. Is not in production yet. Is for following constructions tasks for, obviously, a construction company. Appreciate any help.

Comment: What does `CheckExpression` do? Shouldn't it be smart enough to evaluate the expressions as-is? I'm not sure I understand the need to split them on the `&&` here (i.e. why can't this be a single rule?)

Comment: CheckExpression split by operator (<,> and =) and checks field by field of the class to see if the expression matches.

Comment: Your comment "Shouldn't it be smart enough to evaluate the expressions as-is?" is exactly what I'm looking for. It's an C# expression, so, is there any simpler way to evaluate it? I was looking for something like that but seems to be out of my league. Thanks @Cory

Comment: I think seeing the definition of `CheckExpression` would help here.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it. Seems to go the way that Martin Konicek explains in this link:

http://coding-time.blogspot.com.uy/2011/07/how-to-implement-rule-engine-in-c.html